# My Auto ARIMA showing down trend even if the input has no downtrend

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, arima

I have a timeseries model which has has no downtrend, but my forecasting shows a downtrend and it is not similar to input. Why is this happening? what else can i do to improve ARIMA.

Below is the input image with forecast

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your fitting routine believes the data are best described by an AR(2) process with a nonzero intercept. The forecasts from such a model will converge towards the intercept, which here is apparently a little higher than 300.

Whether this is a "good" or a "bad" forecast is not obvious to me. It may well be that your initial data up to about 2020-10 does not come from the same data generating process as the later data. If you suspect this (and your domain knowledge supports this assumption), you could cut off the initial data and only fit an ARIMA model to later data.

Also, judging from the "[1]" in your output, it seems like you didn't specify the potential monthly frequency, so you won't be getting a seasonal forecast.

> it is not similar to input

Note that [a forecast will likely not be similar to the historical series](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352).

You may find
[*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/)
or
[*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (3rd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp3/)
to be helpful.

Comment: I am using auto arima directly on the dataset. I have few question related to this answer, if you can please answer. 1. how to tackle this non zero intercept? 2. In auto arima, even if i specify P=0,D=0,Q=0 and m=12, my Auto arima still checks for other combination of PDQ. How to prevent this?